# How set values in loose coupled knockout object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, loose-coupling

I am having two objects Project and Setting which I want to couple.
This works fine for presenting the data. However when I want to set the data (in this case with a checkbox) the view is only responding on the first click. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
Settings = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.settingsID = data.settingsID;
    self.projectID = data.projectID;
    self.isVisible = ko.observable(data.isVisible || true);
    return self;
}

Project = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.projectID = data.projectID;   
    return self;
}
```

The key is the projectID

I have defined the following function (to be reused over several view models):

```
my = {
    utils : {}
};
my.utils.getSettings = function (projectid, settings){
    return ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(settings(), function (s) {
            return s.projectID === projectid;
        });
    });
};
```

In my viewModel the relations is defined like this:

```
ViewModel = function  (meID) {
    self.selectedProject = ko.observable();

    // some code setting the value of 'self.selectedProject'…

    // settings 
    self.Settings = ko.observableArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/myService/GetSettingsByUserId",
        data: "userID=" + meID,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (allData) {
            self.Settings($.map(allData, function (item) {
                return new Settings(item);
            }));
        }
    });
    self.getSettings = function (data) { return my.utils.getSettings(data.projectID, self.Settings) };
};
```

In my view I got this HTML:

```
<div  data-bind="with: selectedProject">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.getSettings($data)().isVisible" />
            <label>is Visible</label>
         </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why won't the checkbox update after the first time?
I guess this is due to not being able to update the Setting-object through  'my.utils.getSettings', but why?
Where do I go wrong?

Comment: I am sure that self.isVisible = ko.observable(data.isVisible || true);      (false or true = true,   true or true  = true,  so this always = true.   boolean algebra i think it's called.  I could be wrong, but that is how it looks to me.  as far as i know (something || something else )  only works if something returns as a null or nothing.  I.E  if(something !== null  otherwise 'thisissomething')